# OneWayToSource Binding with C# in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a slider that rotates a label using OneWayToSource binding in XAML to wrap my head around how [Binding Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#the-binding-mode) work.

I got it to work using XAML, but when I tried to achieve the same thing in C#, the slider does not rotate the label.

**XAML Approach (which works):**

XAML:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout">
    <Label x:Name="Label" Text="XAML" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
    <Slider BindingContext="{x:Reference Label}"  Maximum="360.0" Value="{Binding Path=Rotation, Mode=OneWayToSource}"></Slider>
</StackLayout>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**C# approach (which is not working):**

XAML:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout">
</StackLayout>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Slider rotationSlider = new Slider {Maximum = 360.0};
        Label label = new Label
        {
            Text = "Code",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
        rotationSlider.SetBinding(RotationProperty, "Value", BindingMode.OneWayToSource);
        rotationSlider.BindingContext = label;

        stackLayout.Children.Add(label);
        stackLayout.Children.Add(rotationSlider);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the C# approach?

Comment: `rotationSlider.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, "Rotation", BindingMode.OneWayToSource);`

Comment: @Jason thank you! If you post that as a reply I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have it backwards - you want to bind the Slider's `Value` to the Label's `Rotation`

```
rotationSlider.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, "Rotation", BindingMode.OneWayToSource);
```